# How to remove cubbyhole engine from Vault

Tags: hashicorp-vault

Cubbyhole is enabled in Vault by default, but I dont really use it.

Is there any way to remove "cubbyhole" engine from Vault, or even better, is it possible to hide it for specific users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cubbyhole is enabled by default and cannot be [disabled](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/secrets/cubbyhole/index.html#setup).

Cubbyhole is used for response wrapping. You can read more about it [here](https://learn.hashicorp.com/vault/secrets-management/sm-cubbyhole)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, somehow I overlooked that information in the dokumentation. IMO Valt has many nice features, but if I dont want to use cubbyhole, there should be at least option to hide it.

Answer (score 1):

i have tested it and it is possible to hide it via policy:

path "/cubbyhole/*" {capabilities = ["deny"]}